# Мне нужно переименовать файл, но я не понимаю, что не так с моим кодом

Tags: c, windows, шифрование

Мне нужно переименовать файл, но я не понимаю, что не так, файл шифруется, но не меняется название, как нужно использовать функцию rename() правильно.
Мне необходимо изменить имя файла на "encrypt.yes"

```
 #include <stdio.h>                                                                                  
 #include <stdlib.h>  
 #include <string.h>


 int main(void)                                                                                       
 {   

 char new[20];                                                                                                
 char old[20];
 int rename(const char *old, const char *new);                                                                                 
 int ch;                                                                                         
 FILE *fps;                                                                            
 printf("Enter file name (with extension like file.txt) to encrypt : ");
 strcpy(new,"encrypt.yes");
 rename(old, new);                                
 scanf("%s", old);

 fps = fopen(old, "r+");                                           
 if (fps == NULL) {                                                                              
    printf("Could not open file '%s'\n", old);                                                
    return 1;                                                                                   
 }                                                          
 while ((ch = fgetc(fps)) != EOF) {                                                              
    ch += 100;                                                                                  
    fseek(fps, -1, SEEK_CUR);                                                                   
    fputc(ch, fps);                                                                             
    fseek(fps, 0, SEEK_CUR);

 }                                                 

 fclose(fps);                                                                                    

 printf("File '%s' encrypted successfully\n", old);                                            
 return 0;                                                                                       
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, для начала поменяете местами

```
rename(old, new);                                
scanf("%s", old);
```

Ну просто чтоб сначала узнать имя, а потом переименовывать?

Впрочем, тогда у вас

```
fps = fopen(old, "r+");
```

открыть переименованный файл не сумеет. Так что подумайте сами, *когда* вам нужно его переименовать...

Comment: Нет, это не помогло

Comment: А вы как, просто не думая, используете советы? А если я скажу, что с балкона прыгнуть нужно - вы с больницы мне будете писать "не помогло"? :) См. ответ еще раз, последние 4 строки.

Comment: @Jessica, `fps = fopen(new, "r+")`. Открывать нужно новый файл **`new`**, а не старый, которого уже нет (вы же его переименовали).

Comment: О, я поняла, боже, спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: Совсем сегодня устала, ещё и кодить села